# Combine Terms under same Title, unless new = create new Title Wordpress Query

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, wordpress

During a 'foreach' loop, if the same term is detected, only add the page link, otherwise add the term name and page link during a single wp_query?

So for example:

1. Title 1
          Apple Pie
2. Title 1
          Cherry Pie
3. Title 2
          Ham Pie
4. Title 3 
          Goat Pie
5. Title 1
          Noodle Cake

Should Become:

1. - Title 1

     - Apple Pie,
     - Cherry Pie,
     - Noodle Cake
2. - Title 2

     - Ham Pie
3. - Title 3

     - Goat Pie

```
<?php 

$alternate_edition_a = array(
            'post_type'=> 'alternate_edition',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=>10,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
          'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'game_titles',
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'terms' => $gametitle_con,
        )
    )
);
$alternate_edition_query = new WP_Query( $alternate_edition_a );
if($alternate_edition_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $alternate_edition_query->have_posts() ) : $alternate_edition_query->the_post();

$alternate_editionTitlesID[] = get_the_ID(); 

$systemformats_altedition_terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'system_formats');

foreach ($systemformats_altedition_terms as $systemformats_altedition_term) {

if (!has_term($systemformats_altedition_term->slug, 'system_formats', $gameFeatTitleID)) {

    $systemterm_slug[] = $systemformats_altedition_term->slug;

}
}

endwhile; else: endif; wp_reset_postdata(); /*Important to reset away from alternate post type*/ 

$array_notpresentclean = array_unique($systemterm_slug);

/*print_r ($array_notpresentclean);
*/

foreach ($array_notpresentclean as $array_notpresentclean2) {

$alternate_edition_a2 = array(
            'post_type'=> 'alternate_edition',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=>10,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post__in' => $alternate_editionTitlesID,
          'tax_query' => array(
           array(
                'taxonomy' => 'system_formats',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $array_notpresentclean2,
            ),
    ),
);
$alternate_edition_query2 = new WP_Query( $alternate_edition_a2 );
if($alternate_edition_query2->have_posts() ) : while ( $alternate_edition_query2->have_posts() ) : $alternate_edition_query2->the_post();

$currentterm_obj = get_term_by('slug', $array_notpresentclean2, 'system_formats');

if (!isset($var_notpresent)) {

$var_notpresent = 1; ?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>system_information/<?php echo $currentterm_obj->slug; ?>" title="<?php echo $currentterm_obj->description;?>"><?php echo $currentterm_obj->name;?></a>

<?php } ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php 

endwhile; else: endif; wp_reset_postdata(); /*Important to reset away from alternate post type*/ 

unset($var_notpresent);

} 



?>
```

Output is:

1. Cheese

   - Cake is a LIE
2. Steam

   - Cake is a LIE
   - Banananaa Chainsaw
   - Gears of War: Ultimate Edition Windows 10
3. Sega Saturn

   - Fears of Bore
4. Nintendo

   - Banananaa Chainsaw
   - Gears of War: Ultimate Edition
5. Xbox One

   - Banananaa Chainsaw
   - Hamsters of WHAR
   - Gears of War: Ultimate Edition Windows 10
   - Gears of War: Ultimate Edition

Comment: So what's the output of this code, is this not working at all?

Comment: Sorry It works fine to a point. Will update now.

Comment: Please don't edit your original question away to provide an answer. If you've found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer. Otherwise, your question becomes useless for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
$titles = array('Title 1 Apple Pie','Title 1 Cherry Pie','Title 2 Ham Pie','Title 3 Goat Pie');
$list = '<ol>';
foreach ($titles as $value) {
$subtitle = substr($value, 0, 7);
if(!strpos($final,$subtitle )){
   $list .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>' ;
}  else {
    $pos = stripos($list, $subtitle);
    $left_string = substr($list,0, $pos);
    $substring = substr($list, $pos);
    $next_pos = stripos($substring, '<');
    $right_string = substr($substring, $next_pos);
    $current = substr($substring, 8, $next_pos);
    $current = rtrim($current, '</li>');
    $list = '';
    $last = $current . ' '. substr($value, 8);
    $list = $left_string .' '. $subtitle.' '. $last . ' '.      $right_string;
      }
  }
    $final .= '</ol>';
     echo $final;
```

output.

[image]

Comment: Sadly I cannot see this working in a loop. Nor can I even get it working at all for that matter?
I have read up on the functions but they are going way over my head, either way I appreciate the help. I have added a working code above of what I want. Now just working on optimising the queries.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, it can't work in a loop? The code is using foreach loop.

Comment: Meant as in a single WP_Query to then filter/sort those posts without calling more WP_Querys as I have done for a solution. If it does then I apologize as I simply do not understand how to implement despite my reading of the functions.
See above for my working code with intended results.